# Can't find a method to embed/play youtube videos on my web page

Tags: html, flask

I have tried almost every code related to the subject, but none of them seem to work. I am using python/flask to take user input (youtube URL) and I want my output to be the audio of the video. My code right now looks like this:

```
<iframe height="385" width="640">
     <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/{{ videoID }}" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
        allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" height="385" width="640">
</iframe>
```

When I press play I get a cookie error:

```
A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at http://youtube.com/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.
```

Is there really no way to play an audio/video from youtube using a youtube link?

Comment: @Calculuswhiz I tried copying the youtube embed format but I get the same error where the "video is unavailable".

Answer (score 0):

> I tried copying the youtube embed format but I get the same error where the "video is unavailable".

This literally works for me in Firefox `78.0.2`:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return '''<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/JNM5JfjqZAM" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>'''
```

This is the HTML embed code taken directly from the share link on a youtube video.  Plays without errors.

Comment: I get the same error. I have tried to hard code a link as well and it is always unavailable. Is it a problem with chrome?